# Increment the value of TextView of child of particular Parent

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

This is the getChildView inside the Adapter class...

```
public View getChildView(int parent, int child, boolean lastChild, View        view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ArrayList<String> itemDetails= (ArrayList<String>)getChild(parent,child);
        if(view==null)
        {
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout,viewGroup,false);
        }

        TextView textView =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView.setText(itemDetails.get(0));
        TextView textView1(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemdescription);
        textView1.setText(itemDetails.get(1));
        TextView textView3= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.price);
        textView3.setText(itemDetails.get(2));
        final TextView textView2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.counterTextView);
        ImageButton add = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        final ImageButton remove = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            textView2.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(textView2.getText().toString())+1));
            remove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(Integer.parseInt(textView2.getText().toString())==0)
            {
                remove.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                textView2.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(textView2.getText().toString()) - 1));
            }

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

This is the ChildLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/k_meals_rs"
    android:id="@+id/imageView6" />
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_remove_black"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/counterTextView" />

    <ImageButton
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:layout_width="29dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemdescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:maxEms="15"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="₹150"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i want to increment & decrements the value of counterTextView as the the + and - buttons are pressed.. but as i do so it increment and decrements the value of counterTextView in other child in other parents with same index value...any idea how to overcome this problem.. thnx

Comment: could you give us a more detailed explaination of the problem? What changes?

Comment: theres a text view in my expandable list view child layout... countertextview... i want to increment and decrement its values on button add and remove button click... all i want is that the child in which the buttons are clicked only those counterTextView values must change but its changing the value of each counterTextview of all child hving same index in different parent in which the button is clicked

Comment: and this problem occurs while incrementing and decrementing?

Comment: yeah !! actually it does increment and derement the value but other children having the same index of other parents also gets their counter textview incremented and decremented